# A case of self promotion

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I have noticed a few posts promoting a product called HiqPDF wihtin a short time frame, and I wonder if it is the same person using different user names. If this is the case, would it be considered spam? As a side note, the answers promoting this product seem to be on-topic.

Here are some examples:

[user1527860](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527860),
[user1559985](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559985)

There used to be an answer also in this question from yet another user, but it seems it was deleted. Maybe 10k+ users can still see it: [Is it possible to generate PDF using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490028)

Comment: `This html to pdf converter implements all page breaking control you need.` Yeeeeaah sounds pretty spammy

Comment: Are you sure? Because I need some damn serious page breaking control. I got pages breaking all over the place.

Comment: I might comment that if you come across a single user spamming the site, try doing a search for `url:"http://[spamsite.com]*"` based on the link they're posting. A surprisingly large amount of the time, I'll find other users who have posted similar spam but somehow got missed by the community. I do this for every spam flag I see.

Comment: Or even with and without the www, and https, like `url:"*spamsite.com*"`

Comment: @Arjan for blog spam I tend to drop the TLD these days too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Moderator destroys user - for id = 1527860
>   Moderator destroys user - for id = 1559985
>   Moderator destroys user - for id = 1435180

Answer (score 16):

The first user has written two answers that look serious at first glance, but they are both copied verbatim from [the product's docs.](http://www.hiqpdf.com/documentation/html/9c587f18-9414-4a73-b7e8-24902f88f59a.htm)

I say burninate.

[image: Cartoon of guy with a flame thrower]

[Source](http://www.zee-3.com/pickfordbros/archive/view.php?post=238)

Comment: Your photoshop skills are god-like.

Comment: @Adam stolen from here: http://www.zee-3.com/pickfordbros/archive/view.php?post=238

Comment: So Trogdor is for tag burning, and flame-thrower guy is for spam accounts?

Comment: @Robert it wasn't really my intention to start a new meme, but if you put it that way, it makes a lot of sense!

Comment: And who is going to burninate "enter image description here"? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan fixed! ----

Comment: (No problem @Arjan ^_^)

Comment: (That is true @Arjan, why the parenthesis? :-P)

Comment: (Just to indicate my 1st comment was a bit like "as an aside, unrelated, off-topic, what have you", @IAM, but apparently things got out of hand. Cleaning up my comments!)

Comment: @Arjan: needs less hover over, [needs more hoveround](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Htklu.jpg).