# URL searching should not be case sensitive

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, search, spam-detection

When searching by URL pattern it's [often useful to search by domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141675/a-case-of-self-promotion#comment401185_141675).

Currently this search is case sensitive, consider:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2aSTACKoVeRfloW.coM%2a%22

vs

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2astackoverflow.com%2a%22

when spam hunting that's quite unhelpful sometimes [citation needed], spammers aren't notorious for getting little details like capitalisation right.

Can we have an option to make this operator case insensitive or just remove the case sensitivity altogether? It's pretty bad design on the part of the site being linked if case is important enough in a URL that it changes the meaning ever - I think no case sensitivity is the more useful option personally since DNS isn't ever and the rest normally isn't or is just an invalid URL too.

Answer (score 9):

This is caused by the quotes:

- [stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:*STACKoVeRfloW.coM*&submit=search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A*STACKoVeRfloW.coM*&submit=search)

  is case-insensitive (5000+ results and shows **url:*stackoverflow.com*** in the sidebar).
- [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:"*STACKoVeRfloW.coM*"&submit=search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*STACKoVeRfloW.coM*%22&submit=search)

  is case-sensitive (0 results).

I don't know if this is intended behavior, but it could be useful sometimes.

Comment: Wow I never knew that was different in a useful way

Comment: Nice find, for domain-only search. Unfortunately, the quotes are needed when including slashes: `url:*stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/*` ([link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A*stackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F1732454%2F*)) versus `url:"*stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/*"` ([link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*stackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F1732454%2F*%22)).