# Searching on Board and Card Games is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

The search box on Board and Card Games is turning up empty results, even for [obvious searches](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=go). It's been that way [for at least an hour](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/search-failing).

Using square brackets to search by tag [still seems to be working](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D).

Are any other sites experiencing this? We've raised this on our meta, but I'm re-raising here for visibility, since this is a major loss of functionality, and other sites may be affected.

Comment: Eh, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=go+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fboardgames.stackexchange.com) still works. I've never been a particular fan of the SE/SO search engine.

Comment: Nick is on the case...

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a shard issue here when this occurred, it has been fixed and a few measures to prevent it from happening again.

I have also added heavy elastic monitoring to our internal status dashboard so we can identify and fix this kind of thing (or any shard issue) very quickly in the future...without manually digging in the logs of every search node in our cluster.

Comment: Did this hit SO too? http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8653723#8653723

Comment: @Flexo - URL searches are case sensitive: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*LightningChart.com*%22)

Comment: They didn't used to be according to the answer on: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141705/url-searching-should-not-be-case-sensitive, if you skip the quotes. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%2aSTACKoVeRfloW.coM%2a&submit=search works still too.

Comment: @Flexo - that was never intended behavior, URLs are case sensitive so we treat them that way.  You could argue that domain names are not (and you'd be correct), but we don't have that level of control on the search at the moment.