# Why is the URL advanced search operator only finding lowercase URLs?

Tags: bug, status-review, search, hyperlinks

Consider the search [`url:DarthFubuMVC`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3aDarthFubuMVC&searchOn=3) (even [searching globally](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3ADarthFubuMVC)). It returns posts that have that GitHub username in lowercase (https://github.com/darthfubumvc/htmltags), but not ones like [A: fubumvc - rendering a collection as a drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811433/6083675) which have the URL in mixed case (https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/htmltags). (Note that the GitHub URL now redirects to a different name, but I didn't feel like finding yet another example.)

I looked at [URL searching should not be case sensitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141705/323179) (though part of the answer seems to be inaccurate or outdated) which made me realize that quotes would allow me to find the results matching the case I used, but this doesn't help if I want to find everything that matches regardless of case.

Comment: Thanks for raising this @Laurel. I've captured this to share with the product team!